# Why did O-Ren plant the dagger on the balcony?

Tags: analysis, kill-bill

Prior to the Crazy 88 fight scene in Kill Bill Vol. 1, before O-Ren says 'tricks are for kids,' she plants a small smurai, what looks to be a dagger, onto the balcony:

[image]

Both drawing the dagger and her samurai later on from their sheathes is done deliberately slowly.

Is there anything significant to why she'd leave the dagger and that there would be such a focus on her planting it in the balcony? It's a small detail but it stands out to me.

Does it mean anything?